# What could the etymology of Phallodriline be?

Tags: taxonomy, etymology

I'm reading about a series of gutless worms described in several papers as phallodrilines. A search in the World Register of Marine Species shows that there is a subfamily called ["Phallodrilinae"](http://marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=137342), but then, in at least one [paper](https://doi.org/10.1128/AEM.02267-17) this term is used to collectively describe gutless worms in several taxa including Oligochaeta, Annelida, and Clitellata. Since they're also described as club-headed I'm assuming that "Phallo-" is from the Latin for penis, but what would be the rest?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be entirely about etymology rather than biology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Phallus* in Latin means penis, while *drilus* is the New Latin word for Greek

> δρῖλος (drîlos)

which means both *worm* or *erect penis*.

Here you can check some sources corroborating my claim:

[Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Bdellodrilus)

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B4%CF%81%E1%BF%96%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82): δρῖλος (drîlos) means *[verpus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verpus)*

[Liddel & Scott Lexicon](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=dri=los)

[Drîlos meaning penis in Greek](https://www.fishbase.se/summary/Monotocheirodon-drilos.html)

Answer (score 2):

`-o-` linking vowel indicates Greek. `-i-` is Latin, unless the second word starts with a vowel (many `-ectomy` words for example). This is irrespective of declension or gender. Weird I know.

In fact, Latin phallus is from φαλλός.

The second part is worm δρῖλος (drilos). Actually it can also mean penis, but let's gloss over that...